# Can someone describe the behavior of the RPi reset circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi

[image]

Describe the behavior of the RPI RESET CIRCUIT (note that J2 resets the Raspberry Pi Zero if pin 2 is pulled to Ground).
- What happens when the switch is pressed?
- Why do you think this circuit was designed this way? Could it have been simpler?
- Do you have any improvement suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like homework assignment. What research have you done on the subject yourself?

Comment: `Why do you think this circuit was designed this way? Could it have been simpler? - Do you have any improvement suggestions?` are all opinion based questions ... they are not allowed here ... please rephrase them, or remove them

Comment: @patricia if you are happy with my answer, please formally accept it as per [this guidance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

> *What happens when the switch is pressed?*

The circuit (as shown) will not work as intended. R3 is much too large in value (4.7 Meg) to cause the MOSFET to activate because, its gate to source has a 100 kΩ pull-down resistor (R7). This means that the maximum gate source voltage that can be produced is about 70 mV and, this is insufficient for the MOSFET to activate. The [MOSFET indicated](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMV450ENEA.pdf) has a gate-source threshold voltage of 1.3 volts minimum.

The circuit is flawed but, if R3 were less than circa 22 kΩ it would be redeemable.